# Elasticsearch Sort By Epoch MilliSeconds Timestamp

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, timestamp

I have the ES document structure as below.

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "testindex",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "566d9a9d-62d4-4dcd-b3f3-c0598638fa43",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "values" : {
        "isActive" : "false",
        "length" : 18.49,
        "latitude" : 33.69076,
        "accuracy" : 7
      },
      "metadata" : {
        "name" : "866425030270849",
        "type" : "BAT-M1",
        "ts" : "1572493157000"
      }
    }
  },
```

To sort the ES index based on the metadata.ts (date field with format 'epoch_millis'). I am using the following query to get latest record.

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:9200/testindex/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query" : {
    "term" : { "metadata.name" : "866425030270849" }
},
"sort": [
    { "devicedata.metadata.ts": "desc" }
],
"size": 1
```

}
'

But, I am unable to sort the recent record. Please help!

`devicedata` in query is the nested object of metadata.

Comment: Please add mapping

Comment: Your query is inconsistent with what your `_source` is.  you have `metadata.name`, but what is `devicedata` in `devicedata.metadata.ts`?